# How to create a function to output how many characters in each row of a vector are contained in another vector?

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe filled with words and their properties, and one of the columns is titled "Spelling". This has the spelling of every word, with each character separated by a space, like so:

> P L A T E
>
> M A T
>
> R O C K

I have a separate vector of characters with a subset of letters which have been deemed important for the analysis. Like this:

```
important_letters <- c("P","M","E")
```

I need to write a function that, for every row in the dataframe, counts how many characters in the word are contained in important letters and creates a new column in the dataframe with this number. In this example, the new column would contain a 2 for plate, 1 for mat, and 0 for rock.

I have been trying to figure this out and I know the return line of the function should be something like this:

```
return(sum(a %in% important_letters))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
sum_letters <- function(words, imp_letters) {

  sapply(words, 
         function(x) sum(unlist(strsplit(x, split = " ")) %in% imp_letters, na.rm = TRUE)
         )

}
```

Can be called like:

```
df$sum_letters <- sum_letters(df$words, important_letters)
```

Output:

```
df

      words sum_letters
1 P L A T E           2
2     M A T           1
3   R O C K           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

# your objects    
Spelling <- c('P L A T E', 'M A T', 'R O C K')
important_letters <- c("P","M","E")
df <- data.frame(Spelling, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# first, create a new variable (field) in dataframe     
df$important_letters_count <- NA

# this is the function
count_important <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    x$important_letters_count[i] <- 
      sum(strsplit(x$Spelling[i], " ")[[1]] %in% important_letters)
  }
  x
}

# call the functions this way
df <- count_important(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `purrr` and `stringr`. The `map` derivate iterates over your character vector and applies your custom function to each element. Use `str_count` to count matches of your important letters.

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  Spelling = c("P L A T E", "M A T", "R O C K")
)

important_letters <- c("P", "M", "E")

map_dbl(df$Spelling, ~ sum(str_count(.x, important_letters)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
myfunc <- function(v, imp) {
  ptn <- paste0(c("[^", imp, "]"), collapse = "")
  nchar(gsub(ptn, "", v))
}

# sample data
vec <- c("P L A T E", "M A T", "R O C K")
important_letters <- c("P","M","E")

myfunc(vec, important_letters)
# [1] 2 1 0
```

Because this is operating on a vector here, it can easily iterate over frame columns.